# how to check if git autocompletion is installed

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, autocomplete

pls i just followed instructions on downloading git autocomplete bash,pls how do i check the version i downloaded and how do i actaully check if actually it is already installed.
am using ubuntu 20.4 ls.this is what i followed.

[Download the autocomplete script and place it in your home directory:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/
➥contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o
➥~/.git-completion.bash
```

■ Add the following lines to the file ~/. bash_profile :

```
Add the following lines to the file ~/. bash_profile :
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
. ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

....i didnt follow this ..instead,i added the following to my.bashrc file because i am using ubuntu

## Source the git bash completion file

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
source ~/.git-completion.bash
source ~/.git-prompt.bash
fi
```

so how do i check if actaully i have downl

Answer (score 0):

### To setup autocomplete:

-----------*1st Method: worked for me*-------------------

1. Install Git and bash-completion:

```sh
sudo apt-get install git bash-completion
```

check your git version `git --version`

2. To set your name and id

```sh
git config --global user.name "your name"
git config --global user.email "user@id.com"
```

3. restart your bash (new one)

### To Test git autocomplete

*try `git flow`  TAB shows the files under bash Or*

```sh
git chekcout master
```

this will show:

```sh
git: 'chekcout' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        checkout
```

***That's it***

--------------------------*2nd method :(*-----------------------------

### To setup autocomplete:

- Install git `sudo apt-get install git`
- Enter the command it terminal

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
```

- No matter how you acquired the script, you need to rename the file to start with a period. You can do this in the terminal with this command:

```sh
mv git-completion.bash .git-completion.bash
```

Now that we have the file in your home directory with the correct filename, you need to edit either the .bash_profile or .bashrc file found also in your home directory to use the extension. Let’s use the Nano file editor to make the changes assuming you have a .bash_profile file there.

```sh
nano .bash_profile
```

In the editor window type in this code at the end of the file:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
   source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

### Apply the changes

The script will work for all new terminal tabs (or windows), to have it running right away you need to execute it:

```sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

*save it & exit*

### To Test git autocomplete

In new bash try `git flow`  then TAB
Or try

```sh
git chekcout master
```

this will show

```
git: 'chekcout' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        checkout
```

Comment: So how do I use the auto complete feature?

Comment: to check it working:  go to folder with git repository. type `git` then [TAB]  it will show all the available command............